# CSS DIV Container 100% width, min-width 100% (Cover Full-Screen)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a HTML-Page that contains two DIVs. I want each DIV to cover the full screen of the used device. Simple example:

```
<body>
<div class="foo">Some content</div>
<div class="foo">Another content</div>
</body>
```

My css-File looks like this

```
html,body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
min-width: 320px;
height: 100%;
}

.foo {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 }
```

This works, but the content of the first DIV (foo) is cutted off on the bottom of the DIV when 100% of the screen-height is reached. OK, so i tried to change my CSS, changed ***height*** to ***min-height*** on the *body,html* and the *foo*-Element. Now i know: This isn't the solution.

Again: I want the DIV *foo* to have a height of 100% (in relation to the browser-screen), even when there's less content. But in case of long content the ***height*** DIV *foo* should "grow" with the content.

Comment: min-height:100% and scroll auto doesn't work?

Comment: Add margin:0; padding:0; to the .foo.

Comment: It's funny... i started a JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76a2ex5a/ and it works. I don't know whats wrong with my project. I've to check it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
html,body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
min-width: 320px;
}

.foo {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="foo">Some content</div>
<div class="foo">Another content</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm. I don't know if this is what you want to achieve: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tqa8xf51/)

I've just added:

```
 overflow-y:scroll;
```

to your foo element.

But it's quite ugly to have a double scrollbar so I've hided the body scrollbar and just leave the foo one.

If it were my project I would even hide both scroll bars as these days everybody use mause wheel. Only problem is to let users know that there's hidden content so I would add a grafic element at the bottom right of first foo container (something like an arrow down)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

HTML

```
<div class="foo">Some content</div>
<div class="foo">Another content</div>
<div class="foo">Another content</div>
<div class="foo">Another content</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
}
.foo {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qpgdkk/9/)